# About Ajax Encoding

Tags: ajax

Iam using This Code To Call City From Country Code

```
<script>

function getXMLHTTP() { 
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }



    function getCity(strURL) {      

        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }
</script>
```

But The Result Unfortunately Show In ???????

There's A Problem In Encoding

My Main Encoding Is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
```

My Question Is How To Set The Encoding In The Function To Load With My Main Encoding

This Link Contain The Same Problem I Have

[Encoding Problem In AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147247/encoding-problem-in-ajax)

Comment: what browser versions are you trying to support here? do you need to support IE6 or IE5.5? that three-way check for xmlhttp looks like you're trying to support some really old versions of IE. A lot of it probably isn't necessary if you aren't supporting those versions. (and frankly, I wouldn't support them if you've got a choice)

Comment: I Only Need FF And Chrome And Safari Only But How Can I Fix The Encoding Problem

Answer (score 0):

You should try use [**`UTF-8`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: The Problem Is Its Working In Google Chrome No Problem In Encoding But FireFox + IE Not Working I Will try Your Method